# Runtime Error handling

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
    b.myMethod();
}

class B {
    public void myMethod() {
        C c = new C();
        c.errMethod();
    }
}

class C {
    public int errMethod() {
        // Some runtime Error
    }
}
```

Some runtime error in `errMethod()`. My application should not shutdown. What should I do here?

This is one of the Java interview question, we should not be using any exception handling technique. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Google for `Exception Handling` in Java. Start from -> [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This is one of the java interview question, we should not be using any exception handling technique. Is there any other way to handle this.?

Comment: You want to handle an exception without exception handling techniques? That doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Write the code in errMethod in a try/catch block.

```
public int errMethod(){

   try{
    //code goes here
   }
   catch(Exception e){
    // handle exception
   }
}
```